# View inline Docstring in PyCharm rather than External Documentation

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm fetches external documentation for libraries like 'NumPy', 'Pandas', 'SciKit', etc. when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

The displayed documentation is useless. Only the names of parameters for the function are shown.

Instead I'd like if I could get the docstring written next to the definitions of these internal functions in NumPy. This docstring is much more detailed and helpful, but I need to go to the declaration of these functions to see them.

Can't I see them in the 'inline documentation' of PyCharm just by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>?

I've also used IntelliJ and it worked for Java. I could view the JavaDoc by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

I'd like the same here too.

Answer (score 1):

My version of PyCharm (2017.3.2) shows the parameters on top and below that the formatted docstring...

Anyway, you can use `View` --> `Quick Definition` (`Ctrl+Shift+I`) to see the actual function header, with the raw docstring.